# How to compile LINQBridge with MonoDevelopo on .NET 2.0/Windows

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, mono, monodevelop

I'm unable to compile LINQBridge with MonoDevelop for .NET 2.0. The primary issue being that MD has tie-in between the framework and the compiler version. What I want to do is using 3.0 version of compiler on 2.0 framework, is it doable with MD? 
BTW, it can work on VS2008 and SharpDevelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a well known MonoDevelop problem (xbuild does not suffer this bug),

https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=566247

Have to wait till some day MonoDevelop guys fix it.

Comment: Shame that they haven't fixed this long-standing and well known bug

Comment: Their current focus is on MonoTouch and Mono for Android, which keeps Xamarin a fast growing company in the market. I don't blame them for keeping this bug open, as you can always compile without problem by using xbuild at terminal. If anyone is willing to fix it, please fork MonoDevelop at GitHub and submit a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

In MonoDevelop, right click on your **project** (not your solution) and click "Options". Go down to "General" under "Build" and change the framework under the "Target framework" dropdown.

You can compile with most frameworks from there!

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, as I said in my question " What I want to do is using 3.0 version of compiler on 2.0 framework", MD has a tie-in between C# compiler version and framework version (meaning you get the default C# compiler with your framework selection) while in SharpDevelop I can select compiler version and framework version separately. This is what I want for MD.